# Table View, not UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a scroll view on my UIViewController. And on my scroll view I added a Table View and a Table View Cell on it. I used the same code I previously used for my UITableViewController but nothing appears on the Table View. What can I do to fix it?

Here is my code:

```
NSString *const kReward = @"reward";
NSString *const kPoints = @"points";
NSString *const kPicture = @"picture";

@interface RewardsVC ()
@end

@implementation RewardsVC

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

NSDictionary *rewardOne = @{kReward: @"gjshfkasjhdf",
                          kPoints: @"1sfasf",
                          kPicture: @"1.jpg",
                        };

NSDictionary *rewardTwo = @{kReward: @"df",
                          kPoints: @"dfas",
                          kPicture: @"asdf.jpg",
                        };

NSDictionary *rewardThree = @{kReward: @"asdf",
                            kPoints: @"asdf",
                            kPicture: @"sadfsdf.jpg",
                            };

NSString *stringPlaceHolder

NSArray *rewardsArray

rewardsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:

                       rewardOne,
                       rewardTwo,
                       rewardThree,

                       nil];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
// Return the number of rows in the section.

return [rewardsArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSDictionary *rewardItems = [rewardsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

// Item Name
cell.textLabel.text = [rewardItems objectForKey:kReward];


// Item Price
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [rewardItems objectForKey:kPoints];


// Item Image
stringPlaceHolder = [rewardItems objectForKey:kPicture];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: stringPlaceHolder];



return cell;
}
```

Comment: Did you setDelegate and setDataSource on your new tableView?

Comment: How do I do that? @Bejibun

Comment: I think you need to start somewhere more basic than a table view or its controller. Furthermore, you shouldn't be putting a scroll-view in a table-view-controller then putting a table-view in that because (1) the table-view-controller manages its own views and (2) a table view controller already scrolls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In UITableViewCintroller, there is no need to create a table and to set delegate or datasource on it. becouse thats class's defoult fuctinality. but when you are tring to create a tableview on UIViewController's view. you have to Alloc a Tableview and have to set its frame, then set its delegate by either Interface builder window(if you are creating it by XIB or Storyboard) or by code.

I assume that you know how to set frame.
and for delegate.

just Call UItableviewDelegate and UItableviewDatasorce in your .h file

and set in viewDidLoad after allocation

```
tableview.delegate = self;

tableview.datasource = self;
```

and for Iinerface builder ..[image]

Comment: You need conform two protocol `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` in `UIViewController`

Comment: Just like the picture above, you must connect it. Thanks a ton! @longpham

Answer (score 1):

add UITableViewDelegate & UITableViewDataSource

```
@interface RewardsVC : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *tableView;

@end
```

set delegate and dataSource in viewDidLoad after init tableview

```
self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,400,600)];
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
```